React native app with expo push notifications failing on deployed build but not locally
I have a React native app with expo managed workflow, and a database in firebase. When the user logs in on the app, they are asked to consent to push notifications.
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import "../firebaseConfig";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import validateToken from "../api/validateToken";
import { useUser } from "../UserContext";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

import axios from "axios";

const REACT_APP_ANDROID_EMULATOR_BASE_URL = Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.REACT_APP_ANDROID_BASE_URL;
const REACT_APP_EXPO_PROJECT_ID = Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.REACT_APP_EXPO_PROJECT_ID;

const LoginPage = () => {
  const { setUser } = useUser();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigation = useRouter();
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<any>();

  const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      alert("Sorry, we need notification permissions to make this work!");
      return null;
    }

    const token = (
      await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
        projectId: REACT_APP_EXPO_PROJECT_ID,
      })
    ).data;

    return token;
  };

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const pushToken = await registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
      if (!pushToken) {
        setErrorMessage("Failed to register for notifications.");
        return;
      }

      const auth = getAuth();
      const ordinalCaseEmail = email.toLocaleLowerCase();
      const ordinalCasePassword = password.toLocaleLowerCase();
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, ordinalCaseEmail, ordinalCasePassword);
      const user = userCredential.user;

      const token = await user.getIdToken();
      const data = await validateToken(token);
      const response = await axios.get(`${REACT_APP_ANDROID_BASE_URL}/api/users/${user.uid}`);

      setUser({
        uid: user.uid,
        jwt: token,
        deviceToken: pushToken,
        userName: response.data.userName,
        email: response.data.email,
        image: response.data.image,
      });

      if (data.isValid) {
        await axios.post(`${REACT_APP_ANDROID_BASE_URL}/api/user/is-online`, {
          id: user.uid,
          online: true,
        });
        navigation.push("/(tabs)");
      } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid token or other server-side error");
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      const errorMessage = error.response?.data?.error || error.message || "An unexpected error occurred.";
      setErrorMessage(errorMessage);
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    }
  };


This works absolutely fine on a physical device connected by usb and on android emulators.
However, once deployed and I run the installed app on both physical device and emulators, I get this error:
"Encountered an exception while calling native methodd: Exception occured while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.teologi.newMotivationalExerciseApp. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context) first."
I have my google-services.json at root level.
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "12345",
    "firebase_url": "https://motivationalexerciseapp-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
    "project_id": "motivationalexerciseapp",
    "storage_bucket": "motivationalexerciseapp.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:132146:android:12345565",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.teologi.newMotivationalExerciseApp"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "12234665sdffgsdg"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}

my firebase config
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore, writeBatch } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { collection, query, getDocs, deleteDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/functions";

import Constants from "expo-constants";
const { apiKey, authDomain, projectId, storageBucket, messagingSenderId, appId } = Constants.expoConfig.extra;

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: apiKey,
  authDomain: authDomain,
  projectId: projectId,
  storageBucket: storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: messagingSenderId,
  appId: appId,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);

const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage),
});

export { db, auth };

I read here: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#android
and here: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/fcm-credentials/
that i need to add my service account key to the expo dashboard, and so I have, but still no luck. I'm not sure what I've missed. Any help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT 1: I now noticed that I have been using my web app api key in this section:
"extra": {
    "apiKey":"myOldWebApiKey"
}

I got a new one from the android app google-services.json file. I didn't think to switch it out because during development the web api key never failed. Could this be the issue? I'm gonna test it out, but it'll take a while for me to notice any difference due to low priority build queues in expo.
EDIT 2: Still same error and I'm at a loss in regards to what I've missed.

Posting here the solution that worked for me. Might seem obvious, but I couldn't find anywhere that this was the case.
in my google-services.json, i had something that looked like this
{
  "project_info": {
    ...      },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        ...
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "MY-AUTO-GENERATED-ANDROID-APP-API-KEY"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}

and in my app.json, I had this:
 "extra": {
      "REACT_APP_ANDROID_EMULATOR_BASE_URL": "...",
      "REACT_APP_EXPO_PROJECT_ID": "...",
      "apiKey": "MY-AUTO-GENERATED-WEB-APP-API-KEY",
      "authDomain": "...",
      "databaseURL": "...",
      "projectId": "...",
      "storageBucket": "...",
      "messagingSenderId": "...",
      "appId": "...",
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },

So, I basically just had to switch the "current_key" value in google-services.json to my web-app apiKey from app.json (I used the web-app api key in both places, for clarity).
Maybe that was obvious but across multiple threads and walkthroughs I never saw anyone mention this even as a "first just make sure you've checked the api keys match".
Hope this helps someone. Cheers!
